# I am trying to add one to each digit in my problem but I am getting a syntax error that doesn't make sense?

Tags: python

I am trying to add one to each digit in my problem but I am getting a syntax error that says return outside function but it doesn't make sense to me. I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

```
string = ''

num = int(input('Enter a number: '))

num_str = str(num)

for digit in num_str:
    new_digit = int(digit) + 1
    string += str(new_digit)
return string
```

This is the error:

```
Enter a number: 998

File "<ipython-input-6-5ccf9871a3c6>", line 12
    return string
                 ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Comment: wheres the function? Where are you trying to return this to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because return is not inside a Function, it cant return to somewhere. Rewriting the code as follows should fix your error:

```
def myfunction():
    string = ''

    num = int(input('Enter a number: '))

    num_str = str(num)

    for digit in num_str:
        new_digit = int(digit) + 1
        string += str(new_digit)
    return string

mystring = myfunction()
print(mystring)
```

If the task of this little script is adding 1 to the input value you could rewrite it to something more simple.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a return statement outside a function, where should that return to?

```
def yourFunction():
   string = ''

   num = int(input('Enter a number: '))

   num_str = str(num)

   for digit in num_str:
       new_digit = int(digit) + 1
       string += str(new_digit)
   return string

result = yourFunction()
print(result)
```

Comment: Now he also needs to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the return keyword when you aren't in a function. You don't actually need a return here, just delete it.

Edit: Though please note that with your current setup, adding 1 to a digit "9" with append "10" will wrap not wrap around to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Since the code isn't inside a function, you have no place to return to. Just print the string.

```
string = ''

num = int(input('Enter a number: '))

num_str = str(num)

for digit in num_str:
    new_digit = int(digit) + 1
    string += str(new_digit)

print(string)
```